# Merge conflict despite the file not existing

Tags: git

I am trying to pull changes from repo. However, there is an issue:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
.idea/vcs.xml
```

The thing is that this file does not exist in my local repository, so I cannot do anything about this file. Moreover, I already added .idea folder to the .gitignore, but it is somehow not detecting it.

Comment: maybe there are local changes in .idea/vcs.xml? Also It would desirable to know how is the idea folder added to the .gitignore for people to check if that is correct

Comment: .idea/ path is added to .gitignore. and the file .idea/vcs.xml, as I mentioned, was removed in the past, so it doesn't exist now.

Comment: What about fixing the conflict using `git rm --cached .idea/vcs.xml`?

Comment: it's weird, first it seemed to remove it but then the same issue persists.

Comment: That's not actually a *merge conflict*, which is specific to cases that leave the various input files in Git's index. That's more of a *pre*-merge conflict, that prevents the merge from getting started. But see LeGEC's answer.

Comment: “The thing is that this file does not exist” It would be invisible if it existed so how do you know it doesn’t exist?

Comment: _plus_ perhaps it's in `.gitignore`, that doesn't tell us if the other branch has the same `.gitignore` or if the file was added regardless. Judging from the error message, it sounds like the file is added on the other branch. Check with `git ls-tree the-other-branch -- .idea/vcs.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get this error if :

a. the file currently exists (and is not tracked) on your disk :

```
ls .idea/vcs.xml
```

b. and somehow the file is still present on the *remote* branch :

```
git show origin/branch:.idea/
```

Comment: Removing the file from the remote repository solved the issue.